# How to use indices from torch.min to index multi-dimensional tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

Using PyTorch I have a multidimensional tensor `A` of size `(b, 2, x, y)`, and another related tensor `B` of size `(b, 2, x, y, 3)`.

I want to get the index of the minimum value across `dim=1` in `A` (this dimension is size 2), and apply this index tensor to `B` so that I would end up with a tensor of shape `(b, x, y, 3)`.

By using `A_mins, indices = torch.min(A, dim=1)` I am able to get a tensor `indices` of shape `(b, x, y)` where the value is either `0` or `1` depending on which is the minimum value across `dim=1` in `A`. I don't know how to then apply this to `B` to get the desired output. I am aware that `torch.index_select` does a similar job but only for 1D index vectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a more appropriate function would be [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html). You should first apply [`torch.Tensor.argmin`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.argmin.html) (or equally with `torch.Tensor.min`) with the `keepdim` option set to `True` and broadcast the indexer (here reduced `A` since the indexed tensor `B` has an extra dimension):

```
>>> indexer = A.argmin(1,True).unsqueeze(-1).expand(*(-1,)*A.ndim, 3)
>>> out = torch.gather(B, 1, indexer)[:, 0]
```

In terms of shapes:

- `indexer` tensor will have a shape of `(b, 1, x, y, 3)` where the last dimension is essentially a view to the values (we expanded from singleton to three-channel with [`torch.expand`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.expand.html)).
- the resulting tensor `out` will have a shape of `(b, x, y, 3)` after having squeeze the singleton on `dim=1` with `squeeze(1)` or in an equivalent fashion with the `[:, 0]` indexing...